# How to give two users with different profiles and roles the ability to edit some fields but all other users from editing the field(read only)?

Tags: lightning-experience, page-layout, permission-sets, custom-permission

How to give only two users with different profiles and roles  the ability to modify  some fields  but others should have (read only)? I would like to avoid creating a brand new permission set or page layouts just for two users. Is there another way I can do this? Maybe custom settings.

Comment: Permission set is exactly for this purpose. You can use combination of custom settings/validation rules, but I think permission set is the simplest and best solution. + this was it easy to change the allowed users easily

Comment: @LironC  Thanks. I thought so. Was hoping there might be other strategy's people have done.

Comment: @LironC Want to post an answer? Permission Sets are 100% the correct answer.

Comment: Sure. Just post it as answer. I totally agree it is the correct approach, but wasn't sure about it because the request was to avoid permission set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Permission set is exactly for this purpose. You can use combination of custom settings/validation rules, but I think permission set is the simplest and best solution. + this was it easy to change the allowed users easily